# VBA code to ensure that at least one CheckBox is checked

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

I have a UserForm (titled ReplacedParts) that is opened from an original UserForm (frmForm) and it uses CheckBoxes to track what parts were replaced on a rebuild. A total of 26 checkboxes.

After you select the parts replaced, you press "Accept Changes" button. If no CheckBoxes are checked then I want there to be a MsgBox pop up and I don't want the user to be able to continue until at least one box is checked. If at least one is checked, then I want ReplacedParts to hide (thus revealing the original UserForm) and yes, I did include a last box for no parts replaced. Just need a little bit of code that would accomplish this.

I tried a few different ideas I found online but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Can you share your latest code that you tired, and show where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

The code shows validating CheckBox states before enabling a CommandButton. Button only activates if at least one CheckBox is checked.

```vb
' Disable button when userform loading
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.btnOK.Enabled = False
End Sub
' Exit button
Private Sub btnExit_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
' CheckBox click event
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Call UpdateBtn
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    Call UpdateBtn
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
    Call UpdateBtn
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()
    Call UpdateBtn
End Sub
Sub UpdateBtn()
    Dim bCheck As Boolean
    bCheck = False
    For Each c In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(c) = "CheckBox" Then
            If c Then
                bCheck = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Me.btnOK.Enabled = bCheck
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That is useful but not exactly what i was looking for. I could use it though. When you have "For each C in me.controls" where did c come from?

Comment: It's a variable.

Comment: As a variable `c` _should_ have been declared as a `Control` type variable somewhere in the code.  `Option Explicit` at the top of the module would have enforced this.